# Inconsistent behaviour with pretty outlines

Tags: package

**SETUP**:

My `.emacs.d/init.el` reduced to the minimum (I have `auctex` and `use-package` installed)

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-initialize)

(use-package outline
  :hook (text-mode . outline-minor-mode)
  )

(use-package outshine
  :hook (outline-minor-mode . outshine-mode)
  )

(use-package pretty-outlines
  :defer t
  :load-path "custom/"
  :hook ((outline-mode . pretty-outlines-set-display-table)
         (outline-minor-mode . pretty-outlines-set-display-table)
         (LaTeX-mode . pretty-outlines-add-bullets)
         )
  )
```

[pretty-outlines](https://github.com/ekaschalk/.spacemacs.d/tree/master/layers/display/local/pretty-outlines) needs to be in `.emacs.d/custom`

---

**PROBLEM**:

If I have the following LaTeX file:

```latex
% * Test

% test
```

I get the correct display (don't mind the airplane, that's because I should tell my emacs what font to use for this range):

[image]

But if I uncomment the third line

```latex
% * Test

test
```

[image]

I can't figure out what's happening here, looks like there's something messing with some regexps but I really don't understand.